# how to deal with skewed data in structural equation modeling?

Tags: lavaan, structural-equation-modeling

I'm trying to do some simple factor analysis in Lavaan, using 2 factors to explore the relationships between a few variables. However, each time I try to fit the model, it fails to converge. Upon examining the histograms of the dataset, it seems like a few manifest variables (glu and hdl) are skewed right. Based on that, I tried some of the robust estimators in Lavaan but those too failed to converge.

```
mod2 = sim.model <- ' 
F1 =~ glu + trig + hdl + bp_dia + bmi
F2 =~ chol + trig + glu '

fit2 <- sem(mod2, sample.cov.rescale = T, sample.cov = cov(metData), sample.nobs = 342,  std.lv = T) #skewness?
```

here is the output:

```
Warning messages:
1: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
lavaan WARNING: could not compute standard errors!
lavaan NOTE: this may be a symptom that the model is not identified.

2: In lav_object_post_check(lavobject) :
lavaan WARNING: covariance matrix of latent variables is not positive definite; use inspect(fit,"cov.lv") to investigate.
```

If I investigate further, I get:

> inspect(fit2,"cov.lv")
>   F1      F2
>   F1   1.000
>   F2 345.993   1.000

### Is this an an identification problem?

I have 6 manifest variables, therefore 6 * 7 / 2 = 21 unique data values. I am trying to learn 8 + 6 + 1 parameters (paths, residuals and latent variable covariance), therefore I should have 21 - 15 = 6 df.

### path diagrams

Just for reference, here are the path diagrams I am trying to fit. Before fitting the model is structured like this:

```
semPaths(mod2)
```

[image]

After fitting, these are the weights:

```
semPaths(fit2, 'std')
```

[image]

I'm new to SEM modeling and am really just trying to get some practice building models using my Lab's datasets. Would really appreciate some pointers for how to resolve convergance and the positive definate problem.

Comment: The problem is not the skewed data, the problem is that your model is either not identified or is only just identified. You have two factors, one factor has three indicators, two of which are shared with the other factor. That's a bit of a strange model. Can you post your results?

Comment: Also, from the output you post, it looks like normal and asymp are latent variables. But they are not in the model syntax.

Comment: @JeremyMiles thanks for the feedback. yes, i do suppose it's a strange model, but it should still be possible to learn it, right? Also, I have updated my question with regard to the asymp and normal variables. I copied/pasted the wrong data in the question originally, but now it's correct. Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: It looks like an identification problem. The model needs to be identified, and by your parameter count it is, but each parameter in the model also needs to be identified, and that is determined, in part, by the data.  Any time you have a correlation of 345, you probably have an identification problem.